# How to avoid that Playwright ignore multiple key press

Tags: angular, playwright, angular-test

I have a test that is structured as follows.

```
1. Press Enter 10x.
2. check that element XYZ is in focus.
```

The keyboard.press is inside a for loop.

The problem is that due to the press speed, the browser does not recognize all of them.

At the end of the test, ENTER was pressed only 8-9 times. I solved it with a sleep function inside the for loop.

```
for(...){
 this.page.keyboard.press(enter)
 sleep(300)
}
```

Is it possible to avoid a sleep function here and still get a stable test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [delay](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-keyboard#keyboard-press) as option in your `page.keyboard.press()`.
So something like this might work for you:

```
await page.keyboard.press('Enter', { delay: 10 });
```